# Can additional telephony providers be installed by an app developer?

Tags: android

Can an app add/integrate telephony hooks to Android so that it can  provide SMS send/receive functionality that does not use the traditional mobile radio?  Think for example of a virtual SMS provider.

This would be similar to what [CSipSimple](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) does with voice calls for example.  It somehow injects itself into the traditional Android "dial a call" functionality to ask if you want to use the Mobile voice service or one of the SIP providers configured in CSipSimple.

I'm interested in the equivalent functionality for SMS messages though.

Is that possible?  Any pointers to API documentation on how one does it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html) is a documentation on how to write SMS application. You would need to hook to the appropriate broadcasts, probably just `ACTION_SENDTO` with the mentioned schemas should be enough for you.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think this is the right answer.  You appear to have provided information on how to write an SMS app.  I am not looking to write an SMS app.  I want to add/replace the functionality in Android that does the actual SMS sending/receiving -- the part that sends and receives the SMS to/from the carrier.  Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: @Brian That is actually the only way to do that. SMS is sent via SMS app (because only SMS app can actually send the SMS) so if you write your own that does not call SMS Provider but sends it over internet, it will be used for all applications. You cannot write your own SMS Provider. This is also the same way how CSipSimple is integrated.